# Running time analysis of problems with a variable in problem definition

Tags: graph-algorithms, polynomial-time

I am a research scholar in the field of algorithms and complexity theory. The problem that I am currently working is the $[1,j]$-domination problem. Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, $n = |V|$, the problem asks to compute a minimum dominating set $D$, such that all the vertices outside the solution set $D$ have at most $j$ vertices in $D$. Let's say, I have an algorithm for some particular graph class $C$ with the running time $2^j*poly(n)$. Can I say that the problem is polynomial time solvable for graph class $C$? 
 My main question is, should I always consider $j$ to be a constant, can't it be some function of $n$ that ruins everything? Please clarify.

Comment: The usual convention is that if the variable is in the name of the problem, then it can be considered to be a constant. So if the problem name is "[1,j]-domination", then $j$ is considered to be a constant.

Comment: If $j$ is allowed to vary, you can also say that the problem is fixed-parameter tractable, with $j$ being the parameter.

Comment: So, do you mean I could safely say that the problem is polynomial-time solvable for graph class $C$ without worrying about what $j$ can be (as $j$ is assumed to be a constant)? @Laakeri

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be studying the [parameterized complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity) of the problem. This is a branch of Complexity Theory where you add a *parameter*, which is part of the input but is seen as a separate value.

For example, if one looks at the $k$-Clique problem, where $k$ is a fixed constant, then it is trivially solvable in polynomial time with a $O(|V|^k\times|E|)$ algorithm. However, in Parameterized Complexity there is a finer notion called *fixed-parameter tractable*, which states that for an input $(x, k)$, where $k$ is the *parameter* of the input, the problem can be solved in $O(f(k)\times n^c)$ time for some constant $c$. There is a long-standing conjecture that says the $k$-Clique problem, where $k$ is the parameter, is **not** fixed-parameter tractable. If that were true, it would be in a sense harder than other NP-complete problems such as finding a [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) of size $k$, for which there is a known $O(2^k\times |G|^c)$ algorithm.

To answer your question, I would suggest you say the $[1,j]$-domination problem, where $j$ is the parameter, is **fixed-parameter tractable** for the class $C$ like @emil-jeřábek said. That way it is clear that your algorithm runs in $O(f(j)\times n^c)$ time, and that $j$ does not depend on $n$. If you just say that the problem is *polynomial when $j$ is fixed*, it would still be true, but it could still mean that your algorithm runs in $O(n^j)$ time.

As a last comment, if you simply say the algorithm runs in polynomial time for class $C$, without saying anything regarding $j$, then it could mislead people into thinking that your algorithm runs in $O(n^c)$ time.

Comment: In order to prove that the problem is W[1]-hard for some parameter $P$, in the solution size of the reduced instance am I allowed to have $j$ in some form?

Comment: You'd typically say that the problem is W[1]-hard under [FPT-reductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity#:~:text=a%20parameterised%20notion%20of%20reductions%20called%20fpt%2Dreductions) (or simply "under parameterized reductions"), which is a finer version of Karp reductions. In short, yes you can have $j$ in the size of the new instance, but not as an exponent of $n$.

Comment: But wouldn't the reduction collapse if $j$ is some function of $n$? say $n^{0.2}$

Comment: It would, so don't do that. When you express a complexity bound as a function of different parameters they are considered independent. Like, a graph algorithm that runs in $O(|V|^2\times|E|)$ means that the runtime grows quadratically if you increase the number of vertices **while** keeping the number of edges constant.